# Value of string with space

Tags: php

I have a form contains this list:

```
<tr>
  <td>State/Province:   </td>
  <td colspan="3">
     <select style="width:200px" name="state"> 
       <option value="All">All</option>
       <?php for( $i=0;$i<sizeof($states);$i++) { ?>
         <option value=<?php echo($states[$i][0]) ;?>>
           <?php echo( $states[$i][0]) ;?>
         </option> 
       <?php }?>
     </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is the value of `state` when the choice is composed by two or more words. For example if I have the word "New York: only the word "New" is stored in `$_POST['state']`.

- what is the cause of this error?
- how can I do to store all the value in my variable `$_POST['state']`?

Answer (score 8):

Quotes around the value

```
<option value="<?php echo($states[$i][0]) ;?>">

<option value=New York> // No good
<option value="New York"> // Better
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround

```
<?php echo($states[$i][0]); ?>
```

with quotation marks.