# php $_POST not sending full value

Tags: php, mysql

update.php

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM performer WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1") or die("Error : " . mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$id = $r['id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT baned_c, baned_c2, baned_c3 FROM performer_s WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if($result['baned_c'] == NULL) { $res1 = "NONE"; } else { $res1 = $result['baned_c']; }

<?php

echo "<form method=post action=insert.php>";

echo "<select name=country>";
echo "<option value=>NONE</option>";
$country = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT country_name FROM country_list ORDER BY country_name ASC");
while($next = mysql_fetch_assoc($country))
{
if($next['country_name'] == $res1)
{
    echo "<option selected value=" . $next['country_name'] . ">" .     $next['country_name'] . "</option>";
}
else
{
    echo "<option value=" . $next['country_name'] . ">" . $next['country_name'] . "</option>";
}
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<br /><input type=submit value=Update List />";
echo "</form>";
mysql_close();
```

insert.php

```
$country1 = $_POST['country'];
$user = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM performer WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1") or die("Error : " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) or die("Error : " . mysql_error());
$id = $row['id'];
if(isset($country1)) { mysql_query("UPDATE performer_s SET baned_c='$country1' WHERE id='$id'") or die("Error : " . mysql_error()); }
```

hello 2 all, new here and its nice too meet you.

hope you can help me out

Up here are my 2 pages update.php and insert.php

my problem :

if $country1 = $_POST['country']; is a one word country all is good but if its a two word country $_POST only gives me the first word

```
$country1 = $_POST['country'];
if its AMERICA its OK
if its REPUBLIC OF KOREA NOT OK i only get REPUBLIC
```

what can i do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value of string with space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223725/value-of-string-with-space)

Comment: It is a possible duplicate. However, these answers include how to escape a double quote string, that post doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
echo "<option value=" . $next['country_name'] . ">" .     $next['country_name'] . "</option>";
```

for:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $next['country_name'] . "\">" . $next['country_name'] . "</option>";
```

You are, basically, generating this HTML right now:

```
<option value=REPUBLIC OF KOREA>REPUBLIC OF KOREA</option>
```

and you should be generating this HTML:

```
<option value="REPUBLIC OF KOREA">REPUBLIC OF KOREA</option>
```

By the way, do the same thing (add the `"`s) to the other `echo` (the `selected` one).

Comment: In other words, to echo the double quotes `"`, you just have to add a backslash before them, like so: `\"`